# JNLParseException[ Could not parse launch file. Error at line 6.]

Tags: java, applet, java-web-start, jnlp

I am using JNLP to load an Applet on browser. My applet is running fine with java version `Java 1.7.0_25` but facing problem when running with `Java 1.7.0_45`. My error stacktrace is as follows

```
NLParseException[ Could not parse launch file. Error at line 6.]
 at com.sun.javaws.jnl.XMLFormat.throwNewException(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.javaws.jnl.XMLFormat.parse(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.javaws.jnl.LaunchDescFactory.buildDescriptor(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.javaws.jnl.LaunchDescFactory.buildDescriptor(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.javaws.jnl.LaunchDescFactory._buildDescriptor(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.javaws.jnl.LaunchDescFactory.buildDescriptor(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.javaws.jnl.LaunchDescFactory.buildDescriptor(Unknown Source)
 at sun.plugin2.applet.JNLP2Manager.initialize(Unknown Source)
 at sun.plugin2.main.client.PluginMain.initManager(Unknown Source)
 at sun.plugin2.main.client.PluginMain.access$200(Unknown Source)
 at sun.plugin2.main.client.PluginMain$2.run(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Error while initializing manager: JNLParseException[ Could not parse launch file. Error at line 6.], bail out
```

My jnlp file is

```xml
<%@page contentType="application/x-java-jnlp-file" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@taglib uri="/struts-tags" prefix="s"%>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jnlp spec="1.0+" codebase="ds">
    <information>
        <title>D S Applet</title>
        <vendor>ABC</vendor>
    </information>
    <security>
      <all-permissions/>
    </security>
    <resources>
        <!-- Application Resources -->
        <j2se version="1.6+" href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se"/>
        <jar href="ds.jar" main="true"/>
    </resources>
    <applet-desc name="MyApplet" main-class="pkg.MyApplet" width="600" height="600">
        <param name="separate_jvm" value="true"/>
        <param name="urlToGetFilesFromServer" value="${urlToGetFilesFromServer}"/>       
        <param name="urlToSendFilesToServer" value="${urlToSendFilesToServer}"/>
        <param name="recordIds" value="${recordIds}"/>
        <param name="urlAfterSuccess" value="${urlAfterSuccess}"/>
        <param name="jsonMapOfFilenameAndChecksum" value='${jsonMapOfFilenameAndChecksum}'/>
        <param name="checksumOfJson" value='${checksumOfJson}'/>
        <param name="pkcsConfigFilePath" value="${pkcsConfigFilePath}" />
    </applet-desc>
    <update check="background"/>
</jnlp>
```

I am not getting the problem - problem with my jnlp file or problem with java version?

Comment: "ds" is not a valid URL for your codebase

Comment: Be sure to check the JNLP using JaNeLA, available at my [share drive](https://drive.google.com/drive/#folders/0B5B9wDXIGw9lUnJaUjA2cmlVRE0).

Comment: @Lonzak `ds` is not there at code, I have put it here only for sample purpose. BTW I got the problem, Problem was not in jnlp file, It was somewhere else.

Comment: @AndrewThompson After checking with JaNeLA, I got the problem. It was not in JNLP. It was somewhere else. But now I am facing some another problem - how to pass a variable value (that is having double quotes) as a parameter to applet through jnlp?

Comment: *"(that is having double quotes)"*  Escape the quote character.  Or better still, HTML encode it using `&#34;` or `&quot;`..

Comment: I have tried that too. Even when I have tried to use single quotes, It is showing security error - `security: Rejecting argument with illegal chars`. My data is a json object.

Comment: See also the edit to that last comment..

Comment: BTW - when posting JNLP content, please post it as it might be seen by **the client.**  This can be done easily by having a `JEditorPane` access it by URL from a server.  Please also update the question with that content.  If a value is `&quot;Joe&quot;%20Dimaggio` and it is necessary to anonymize it, change it to `&quot;John&quot;%20Smith` or something, but otherwise leave it as-is.

Comment: @Ankit: If you got the problem please post an answer so that others can benefit from it, too....

Comment: @Lonzak Actually the problem was in my server side code, not in JNLP file.

Comment: Ok then write it as a solution or delete the whole thing but don't leave it hanging here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was in my server side code, not in JNLP file.